# Unable to run Personal.xlsb Macro, unless "stepped into"

Tags: excel, vba

A macro that will be used by multiple people regularly will not run correctly, unless "stepped into" and the line clicked on after pressing "F8"

The macro will be stored within Personal.xlsb. The theory of operation is that we will export data from a third party vendor onto our personal workstations with a file extension of .xlsx. Then, we will open it, enable macros, run the macro, and the third party data will be formatted, and a predetermined range will be copy and pasted below the last used row. The formatting is working as intended, but the predetermined range is not being pasted onto the worksheet, unless I "step in", run each line with "F8" but also click back into the personal.xlsb module that I am working on after hitting "F8".

```
Sub ILARNG_TRANS()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Workbooks.Open ("\\PRIVATESERVER\Trans Affecting and Non\END_OF_REPORT.xlsx")

    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim CopyLastRow As Long
    Dim DestLastRow As Long

    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("END_OF_REPORT.xlsx").Worksheets("404")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    DestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    wsCopy.Range("A1:E" & CopyLastRow).Copy _
        wsDest.Range("A" & DestLastRow)
    Workbooks("END_OF_REPORT.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

I want to run this macro without having to "stepping into" and running with "F8"

Comment: Not the issue, but there should be a `wbCopy` assigned at `Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open("\\path\file.xlsx")`; no need to later dereference it from the `Workbooks` collection, you've already received (and discarded) a reference to that object when you opened it. That makes `Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Worksheets("404")` and similarly, `Workbooks("END_OF_REPORT.xlsx").Close` should be `wbCopy.Close`.

Comment: turn application.screenupdating to true at the end. that might fix it

Comment: Do you mean `wsDest` to be in `Personal.xlsb`? Because that's what `ThisWorkbook` should be referring to, if that's where this code is written in.

Comment: ScreenUpdating = True, unfortunately did not fix it

Comment: wsDest will be the exported file (also the primary file). wsCopy is the workbook that will be opened, copied, pasted onto wsDest, then closed.

Comment: So what will happen is I will open the exported file, enable macros (which is enabling the my Personal.XLSB Macro, residing within my XLSTART folder), and then run the macro on the main workbook (for example, 9180_404.xlsx being the file that I want to run the macro on), then save the report.

Comment: Change Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") to Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")